# Nested parallel RC inner capacitor voltage function

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis

Fiddling a little bit with RC circuits, I thought of this DC circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsXsvp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Trying to fully define this circuit, I deduced this :

\$V_{C1}(t) = 5*(1 - e^{-t/(R1 * C1)})\$

\$V_{R1}(t) = 5 - V_{C1}(t)\$

\$V_{R2}(t) = V_{R1}(t) - V_{R3}(t) \$

\$V_{R3}(t) = V_{C2}(t)\$

The thing is, I don't see how to figure out \$V_{C2}(t)\$... The thing is, that I don't know the way C2 charges because it's fed by \$V_{R2}\$ which is not a DC voltage nor a sinusoidal voltage (or any voltage that has a frequency anyway I believe).

So I'm pretty much stuck... How to solve this kind of problem (a capacitor being fed partly by another capacitor) ? And in general, how to solve a capacitor's charging voltage equation from a varying voltage source of equation \$V = f(t)\$ ?

Comment: The first equation you wrote seems incorrect as the current in \$R_1\$ surely feeds \$C_1\$ but also \$R_2\$. I would determine the transfer function in Laplace and determine the response in the time domain then. As a side remark, for instantaneous variables, use lower case notation like \$v_1(t)\$ for instance.

Comment: I guess that's the joy of being just a (yet) uneducated hobbyist.. Discovering that even for problems that feel simple, there's a whole new piece of math for you pleasure/pain, however you feel like.

Comment: In this case, I would recommend that you become familiar with simpler circuits, 1st-order (1 cap or 1 inductor) and then slowly complicate the exercise with more elements as you make progress. Good luck : )

Comment: It's getting into total subjective territory, but, do you have 
learning resources for RC circuits ? All the resources I know *just* focus on the basic 1 cap + 1 res, and doesn't tackle anything else, which I guess *impedes* (heh) my progression. If you'd like to answer that, could you create a chatroom ?

Comment: You can look at this book for a start on analyzing electrical networks: https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Circuit-Transfer-Functions-Introduction/dp/1119236371/ref=la_B001IOH604_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1461931295&sr=1-3 It describes the fast analytical techniques implemented to determine transfer functions using time constants \$\tau=RC\$ and \$\tau=\frac{L}{R}\$.